# How to insert session incremented values into database table using php?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I need to insert session incremented values into database,here i can possible to increment values like 0001,0002 and so on,but the problem i can't insert these incremented values into database table.

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
            $username="root";
            $password="sha12345";
            $hostname="localhost";

            $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die("Could not connect to database");

            $select = mysql_select_db("sha", $dbhandle);
            session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['rid']))$_SESSION['rid']=0;
            if(!empty($_POST['register']))
        {   
            $_SESSION['rid'] = $_SESSION['rid']+ 1;
            $input = $_SESSION['rid'];
            str_pad($_SESSION['rid'], 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

            $calender=$_POST['datum1'];
            $time=$_POST['timepicker_6'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO receipt(Bill_number,Date,Time) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['rid']}','$calender','$time')");
    require("fpdf/fpdf.php");

        $pdf=new FPDF();
        $pdf->Addpage();
    $pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",18);
        $pdf->Cell(0,10,"Receipt number:". str_pad($_SESSION['rid'], 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT),0,0,'C');
        $pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",18);
        $pdf->cell(0,10,"Date:{$calender} ",0,1,'R');  
        $pdf->cell(0,10,"Time:{$time}",0,1,'R');
    $pdf->output();

        }
    ?
```

Really thanks everyone,now i can insert session incremented values properly into database table after used varchar for Bill_number.

But now the problem is i can't able to insert session incremented values into database in format of 0001,0002 and so on.

Really thanks if help me again.

Comment: Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of the deprecated `mysql`, etc. etc.

Comment: prepare query before passing into `mysql_query` & then print it.

Comment: Column `Bill_number` is varchar type?

Comment: okk,Thank you Apul Gupta,No,i was used column Bill_number as int type.

Answer (score 0):

You have taken session value in `$_SESSION['rid'] = $_SESSION['rid']+ 1;` this line, but you will get new session value only after page is refresh so its not happening here,so at last you are passing same older value available in `$_SESSION['rid']` variable to the query. Please take a look to below given solution.

```
  $IncrementValue = $_SESSION['rid']+ 1;
```

And replace the `{$_SESSION['rid']}` with `$IncrementValue` in query. Now your query will look like:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
             receipt(Bill_number,Date,Time) 
             VALUES ($IncrementValue,$calender,$time)
            ");
```

also you need to change in bellow line

```
  str_pad($IncrementValue, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Session variables can be used on same page.

Comment: @Kyslik- I edited like you told me,but it's getting error like undefined  Undefined index: rid.Actually i edited my program again for you understanding easily.can you check it and tell me.really thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Please check:

1. Column **Bill_number** is `varchar` type
2. You should have `session_start();` in the beginning of PHP script, otherwise your session variable will be treated as local variable
3. Prepare query before passing into `mysql_query` & then print it.

Also, you can replace `$_SESSION['rid'] = $_SESSION['rid']+ 1;` with `$_SESSION['rid']++;` in your code.

Comment: Thanks Apul Gupta,okk,i forgot to add session_start(); in the begining of PHP while upload,sorry :( ,now i edited my program correctly,can you check again and tell me the correct way.

Comment: Always keep `session_start` in the beginning of script.